# Annihilator condition for a module to be primary

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with $1$, and $M$ an $R$-module for which the annihilator $I$ of $M$ is contained in a maximal ideal $m$ of $R.$ Is it necessary that $M$ be $m$-primary or that it have an $m$-primary submodule?
 I am trying to show the existence of a nonzero $R$-module homomorphism from the module $M$ to the injective envelope $E(R/m)$ of $R/m.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a counterexample:

Let $R=K[x,y],M=K[x,y]/(xy),$ where $K$ is a field. Then $\text{ann}_R(M)=(xy)\lhd R$ which is contained in $\mathfrak{m}=(x,y)\lhd R.$ Viewing $x,y$ as elements of $M$, note that $\text{ann}_R(x),\text{ann}_R(y),$ respectively, are $(y),(x),$ respectively, and so $\{(x),(y)\}\subseteq\text{Ass}M,$ the set of associated primes of $M$. Thus, $M$ is not $\frak{m}$-primary. I now claim that $M$ has no $\frak{m}$-primary submodule.

Suppose, for contradiction, that $N$ were an $\frak{m}$-primary submodule of $M$. (Notice that everything in site is finitely generated - just in case I need that!) Now since $\frak{m}$ is an associated prime of $N$, there is an element $0\neq n\in N$ with $\text{ann}_R(n)=\mathfrak{m}=(x,y).$ So we have $xn=0=yn$ in $N$ and hence also in $M$. So $xn,yn\in (xy)$ and we must have $n\in (x)\cap(y)=(xy)=0$ in $M$. This is a contradiction with our assumption on $n$ and so no such submodule $N$ exists.

Comment: I hope that's correct!

Comment: I apologise for being so long responding. My computer was in the shop being scrubbed of a virus. I believe your example is, indeed, a counterexample. Thank you for your trouble in providing it. I think I can show what I wanted via a different approach, which, incidentally, does not seem to be any more difficult than the approach I was trying to take. Thanks again.

Comment: A small problem with the example. Upon closer inspection, the ideal $\mathfrak{m}=(x,y)$ is not a maximal ideal of $R = \mathbb{Z}[x,y].$ The quotient $R/\mathfrak{m} \cong \mathbb{Z},$ which is not a field. However, I believe there is no problem working with $k[x,y],$ where $k$ is a field. So, I still accept your answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you for spotting that. I've edited the answer accordingly.